# reverse geocoding api with no limitation?

Tags: reverse-geocoding

I was wondering for reverse geocoding api, which doesn't apply any per day or monthly limit on the data? Till now all i have got is google api and geonames api. 
I need to get postal code from latitude and longitude of location.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own PostGIS Server that runs on PostgreSQL.

1. Install PostgreSQL
2. Install PostGIS
3. Download a Zipcode file either as points or as geometry

Zipcode information can be downloaded for the US from the US Census Bureau and other sites.  Note that many US Postal Zip Codes don't have a physical location/boundary, which explains why many services could potentially report a different location for some zip codes.